# Dummy WIA Driver

Tags: wia, twain

I have an application that uses WIA 2.0 however the scanners that we have in the office are not compatible with WIA.

Is there any dummy driver such as the TWAIN Dummy driver (`twainkit.exe`) for WIA that we can actually test with like a fake image? Note this has to support Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: You can try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552711.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also WIAonTwain, http://sourceforge.net/projects/wia-on-twain/

From the description in sourceforge, "A WIA on TWAIN driver implementation designed to expose all necessary scanner functionality while adhering to the WIA 1.0 and WIA 2.0 specification and achieving compatibility with all WIA compliant applications." Also, it is made by the TWAIN working group.